# Properly formulating stokes theorem problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vector-fields, calculus, models

I am interested in applying stokes theorem to a velocity field resulting from the flow of infinitely many helixes, where each helix flows in the horizontal $x$ direction, has the same diameter of circulation, and each helix centerline lies on the $y$ datum, and the helix velocities are proportional to the distance their centerline is from the ground. My key assumption is that heilix velocity proportionally to the helix centerline $z_0$, so the velocity is $c z_0$, where $c$ is a constant equal to $\frac{1}{time}$

I tried doing this with parametric equations, first describing the position $P$:

$P(t, z_0) = c z_0 t\ \hat{i} + cos(c z_0 t)\ \hat{j} + (z_0 + sin(c z_0 t))\ \hat{k}$

$\frac{d P(t, z_0)}{dt} = c z_0\ \hat{i} - z_0 sin(c z_0 t)\ \hat{j} + (z_0 cos(c z_0 t))\ \hat{k}$

where $z_0$ is the helix centerline and $c$ is a constant relating particle speed to helix centerline height, with units of $\frac{1}{time}$

I call the velocity field $V$, assuming it's equal to $\frac{d P}{dt}$. Now I can integrate across $z_0$ to find the velocity field resulting from infinitely many helixes:

$V(t) = \int ( c z_0\ \hat{i} - z_0 sin(c z_0 t)\ \hat{j} + (z_0 cos(c z_0 t))\ \hat{k}) dz_0  = c \frac{z_0^2}{2}\ \hat{i} - \frac{sin(c z_0 t) - c t z_0 cos(c t z_0)}{t^2}\ \hat{j} + \frac{c z_0 t  sin(c z_0 t) + cos(c z_0 t)}{t^2} \ \hat{k} $

Something about my formulation seems wrong. Did I do this correctly? I want to apply stokes theorem to this, which will require making a control volume in the same coordinate system. I'm not sure how to do the control volume using my parametric formulation of the helix shapes.

**EDIT**
Here is a schematic showing some of the helixes. The redder colors represent greater wind speeds and the more purple colors represent lesser wind speeds.

[image]

Comment: I don't think I can undersatnd this problem fully. Can you paste some schematic?

Comment: @Feynman I posted a picture

Comment: I think $dP/dt$ is the velocity field, and it isn't necessary to integrate over $z_0$. I don't understand what's the PHYSICAL meaning of $z_0t$. In your model, $z_0$ is the position, so $[z_0t]=m. s$.

Comment: the physical meaning is that the velocity increases with height, directly proportional to the height of the helix centerline $z_0$

Comment: But what does $sin(z_0t)$? $z_0t$ should be dimensionless.

Comment: @Feynman I think $z_0 t$ should actually have units of length. Really there is a constant $c$ equal to $\frac{1}{time}$. I added this constant to my question.